# Loading dynamically generated pdf to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf

I created a little application which receives a form via `POST` method and in return generate a pdf file using the form data.

I would like to load the response pdf file into a `<iframe>` for printing purposes.

All i found works only if you know your pdf file source or you can set your pdf generator url.

```
<iframe src='yourpdf.pdf'>
```

or

```
<iframe src='path/to/your/script'>
```

My issue is that i have to post my form first to generate the pdf file.

Is there any way to do it?

If not how should i pass the form data else since via the url would be really messy.

Comment: I do that more or less but what load in the iframe is a form, anyway the idea is the same. You should run this: $('#myIframe').attr('src', "/Comprobacion/UpLoadTAE/" + idRLine);

Comment: @Glegan Thank your for your quick answer. i forget to mention I'm not a Jquery expert can u be a more specific?

Comment: OK, the POST will return the name of pdf? or what you get from the POST?, you could show a little more of your code?

Comment: @Glegan Its a simple html form with an action which is point to the pdf generator script. the script will return the PDF file. Atm it will be starting to download automatically by the browser after form submission

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Glegan idea, i load the form in the iframe therefore i don't have to load the pdf file in it.